# CUDA program is slower than CPU program, but the kernel is faster?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, parallel-processing

The title of the question might sound confused, but in fact.. it is!

I have a program which execute this line

```
new_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2 + CPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX();
```

the "+" operators are overloaded and I created a simple matrix class to simplify code reading.

```
    myMatrixClass operator+ (const myMatrixClass& mt)
{

    myMatrixClass result(this->rows, this->columns);
    // Sum each couple of values
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            result.values[i*columns+j] = this->values[i*columns+j] + mt.values[i*columns+j];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have another version of the program which calculates the third term with CUDA

```
new_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2 + GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX();
```

After profiling a bit I discovered that:

the entire GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX() function is FASTER than the CPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX() function (memory transfers included), so CUDA did its job..

but the line 
    new_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2 + CPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX();
is FASTER than 
    new_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2 + GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX();

what could cause this weird behavior?
CPU caching something?

Since this line is executed several times (it is needed for a rendering), the entire CUDA program is slower than the CPU version, but as I said the GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX() function is faster than the CPU_GIVE_ME_A_FUNCTION()

Comment: What exactly is the question? This doesn’t surprise me at all. After all, the memory bandwidth of the GPU is extremely low compared to the CPU.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: GPUs usually have *much higher* memory bandwidth than their host CPU. What is slow is the PCI-e bus between the two.

Comment: Is `GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX()` performing GPU memory allocation and data transfer to/from the GPU at every call?

Comment: @talonmies Yes, that’s what I meant. Thanks for clarifying my admittedly murky statement.

Comment: sadly yes, but I tried to keep as much memory as possible on the device (GPU) and take back just the matrix data. Anyway I profiled the time the entire GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX() takes and, memory transfers included, it is faster than the CPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX() function. The problem should be elsewhere

Comment: A slow GPU 8400M, CUDA 4.1, everything under Windows and visual studio

Comment: It sounds like you might be experience side effects of the [WDDM driver batching mechanism](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=160277). Try inserting a `cudaStreamQuery(0)` call after the kernel launch in `GPU_GIVE_ME_A_MATRIX()` and see whether that changes the performance of the code.

Comment: I disabled TDR so it should not matter, but I discovered that the code generated by the compiler (everything is the same excepted the convolution that is performed in the GPU instead of the CPU) in the two cases is different: http://nopaste.info/b124a09d88.html

Comment: -> take a look at the lines I highlighted, they're absolutely useless.. and the GPU code seems bloated (why so much stack use?)

Comment: Did you cudaDeviceSynchronize() before starting and stopping the timer?

Comment: used queryperformancecounter for windows systems

Comment: If you don't understand the question, don't downvote please. Just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU version puts the resulting matrix in the CPUs cache (or at least it can), while the the result of the GPU version has to be read in from system memory. While this is desired in most cases (you don't want to pollute CPU cache upon every device to host transfer), it means that CPU read of this data (the first time at least) will be slower than if the data was computed host-side.

It is generally encouraged to keep memory on the device as long as possible, and to transfer as little of it back as you can. In this case, it sounds like the GPU isn't being given enough work to make it worthwhile. Perhaps a larger task than computing a single matrix can be given to the GPU?